# Renaming series column names after applying function and returning mutiple dataframes

Tags: python, function, pandas, return-value, rename

I have a function that returns multiple series, and want to rename the series names.

```
 def myfunction(MyDataFrame, UniqueID, Var1, Var2):
     RunningSumA = MyDataFrame.groupby([UniqueID])[Var1].cumsum().reset_index()
     RunningSumB = MyDataFrame.groupby([UniqueID])[Var2].cumsum().reset_index()

     return pd.Series([RunningSumA, RunningSumB])


 Result = myfunction(MyDataFrame, UniqueID, Var1, Var2)
```

When I look at the first few rows of the resulting series, this is the result:

```
Result[0].head()

  index    0
0  216646  0
1  216647  0
2  216648  0
3  216649  0
4  216650  0
```

I want to rename `index` and `0` into something meaningful inside the function. I've tried to play around with renaming the columns, but could not get them renamed. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you show what you tried that didn't work, the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) are pretty clear how to do this and there many questions here about performing this

Comment: Just before the return, I tried:                                                  RunningSumA = RunningSumA.rename(columns={'index':'UniqueID', '0':'Total'}) but it looks like this is being overridden by return pd.Series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) takes a name argument which populate the column name:

```
...
RunningSumA = MyDataFrame.groupby([UniqueID])[Var1].cumsum().reset_index(name="suma")
RunningSumB = MyDataFrame.groupby([UniqueID])[Var2].cumsum().reset_index(name="sumb")
...
```